# How to update all values of a matrix with a multiple of their existing values

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix, and I want to multiply all the values in each element by Sqrt[2/3]. Here is the code.

```
    m = Table[
    If[(n)^2 + (j)^4 + (k)^3 + (l) == 0, {n, j, k, l}, Nothing], {n, 
    0, 10, 1}, {j, 0, 10, 1}, {k, -10, 0, 1}, {l, -10, 0, 1}] // 
    Flatten[#, 3] & // Select[Length@# > 0 &]; m // MatrixForm
```

So the columns of the matrix correspond to the values of (*n,j,k,l*). Now I want to create a new matrix, where I introduce a counter value that starts at say 0.01 and increments by 0.01 with each iteration, call it *a*++.

The new 3 column matrix will take the value of (*n,j,a*) and put it into the matrix as the first row, and also (while keeping the same value of *a*) will also add (*k,l,a*) as the second row and then move the next row of the original matrix and so the same process, with the counter *a* incremented.

This code, with the help of people here, is:

```
    Join @@ MapIndexed[Partition[#1, 2] /. x_?VectorQ :> Join[x, 0.01 #2] &, m]
    ListPlot3D[%, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]
```

However, before plotting this, I want to also update each element of the value of *a* to the value of *a* times 1/Sqrt[3].

The previous post is here: [Create a new matrix from an existing matrix and then plot it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213722/create-a-new-matrix-from-an-existing-matrix-and-then-plot-it)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, `ListPlot3D[% / Sqrt[3], PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]`?

Answer (score 1):

Using an alternative method suggested in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/213752/125) to generate the two matrices:

```
ClearAll[l, n, k, j]
m2 = Values @ Solve[{Total[{l, n, k, j}^Range[4]] == 
      0, -10 <= l <= 0 && -10 <= k <= 0 && 0 <= n <= 10 && 
      0 <= j <= 10}, {n, j, k, l}, Integers];

m2 == m
```

> True

```
new2 = ArrayReshape[MapIndexed[Riffle[#, .01 #2[[1]], {3, -1, 3}] &, m2], 
  {2 Length@m2, 3}];
```

You can get the desired result by using `.01 /Sqrt[3]` instead of  `.01` as the increment:

```
new2a = ArrayReshape[MapIndexed[Riffle[#, .01 #2[[1]] / Sqrt[3], {3, -1, 3}] &, m2], 
  {2 Length@m2, 3}];
```

Alternatively, you can scale the matrix `new2` by multiplying each row with `{1,1, 1/Sqrt[3]}` or using `ScalingTransform[{1,1,1/Sqrt[3]}]` on `new2`:

```
new2b = {1, 1, 1/Sqrt[3]} # & /@ new2;
new2c = ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 1/Sqrt[3]}]@new2;

new2a == new2b == new2c
```

> True

```
ListPlot3D[new2a]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just multiply your matrix by `1/Sqrt[3]`

```
aa = RandomInteger[5, {2, 2}];
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 5 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

```
1/Sqrt[3] aa // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: that is okay for the first part - but I do not know how to multipy the new matrix represented by this code    
 Join @@ MapIndexed[Partition[#1, 2] /. x_?VectorQ :> Join[x, 0.01 #2] &, m]
    ListPlot3D[%, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]